# LibGdx Box2D Touch Input Movement

Tags: libgdx, movement, touch

I've created 2 buttons for movement in my game but when those button are being pressed, the character gets basically thrown away and by pressing only once  the movement it's continuous and i don't understand with box2D what's the right way to handle the movement of the character

The code looks something like this:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private SuperShooter game;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam; 
    private Viewport gamePort; 
    private Hud hud;
    private OrthographicCamera guicam;

    Rectangle wleftBounds;
    Rectangle wrightBounds;
    //Vector3 for keeping the coordinates
    Vector3 touchPoint;
    //Texture for touch buttons
    Texture leftRegion;
    Texture rightRegion;

    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    //Box2D Variables
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    private John player;

    public PlayScreen(SuperShooter game){
        this.game = game;
        gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new StretchViewport(SuperShooter.V_WIDTH / SuperShooter.PPM, SuperShooter.V_HEIGHT / SuperShooter.PPM, gamecam);

        hud = new Hud(game.batch);
        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("Level1WithObjects2.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/SuperShooter.PPM);

        gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth()/2, gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2, 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0,-15), true);
        new B2WorldCreator(world, map);

        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        player = new John(world);


        guicam = new OrthographicCamera(480, 320);

        guicam.position.set(480/2F, 320/2F, 0);

        wleftBounds = new Rectangle(0,0,80,25);
        wrightBounds = new Rectangle(80, 0, 80,25);

        //creating the vector
        touchPoint = new Vector3();

        //Instantiating Textures
        leftRegion = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("back.png"));
        rightRegion = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("next (1).png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void handleInput(float dt){

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.R)){
            game.setPlayScreen();
        }

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) continue;
            guicam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
            if (wleftBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)){
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.02f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);
            }else if (wrightBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)){
                player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.02f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);

            }
        }

    }


    public void update(float dt){
        handleInput(dt);
        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2); 
        gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x; 
        gamecam.update();
        guicam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        //render our Box2dDebugLines
        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);  

        hud.stage.draw();

        //draw touch buttons
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(leftRegion, wleftBounds.x, wleftBounds.y, wleftBounds.width, wleftBounds.height);
        game.batch.draw(rightRegion, wrightBounds.x, wrightBounds.y, wrightBounds.width, wrightBounds.height);
        game.batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        b2dr.dispose();
        hud.dispose();
    }
}
```

So, the player moves with 0.2f and -0.2f and if i change it to 0.1f it won't move at all..and the movement feels like it's too fast, you touch it once and the character keeps moving :( are there any other ways to do this?or what's wrong with this code? should i change the way that the force it's applied to the character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly. I am not sure that you are asking about a platformer or a top down styled game. And for reducing speed overtime you should do it by multiplying the speed to a float <1 for example:

```
          Player.speed *= 0.75f;
```

Those value is common for physics place the code in update method or something that ran each frame.
Btw sorry if it is not clear as i never worked with Box2d before.

And if those method wasnt working i suggest you make your own simple physics engine.

Another notes: some physics engine have a density field/variable on each object, maybe changing that would work.